# ng-repeat Circular Reference Screen Refresh

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm a noob to AngularJS. As a learning exercise I am creating a typeahead control.

The typeahead is comprised of a text box for filtering the options, an unordered list for displaying the menu of short-listed options, and a Show/Hide button for manually toggling the list.

The text box filters the li elements using ng-repeat. When selecting an li item from the list, I populate the text box with the selected value, and then hide the list.

```
<div class="xtab-typeahead" ng-controller="xTabTypeAheadCtrl">

  <input type="text" class="xtab-typeahead-search" placeholder="{{type}}" ng-model="query.id" ng-focus="showMenu()" ng-init="query.id = undefined" />
  <button ng-click="toggleMenu()">Show/Hide</button>

  <ul class="xtab-typeahead-menu" ng-class="{true:'active',false:''}[isActive]">
    <li ng-repeat="item in menuItems | filter:query" 
        ng-click="hideMenu(); query.id = item.id">
      {{item.id}}
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

My issue is that when the value is assigned to the text box, the list is momentarily filtered to the one option selected (because the text box is also the source of the ng-repeat filter), before hiding the menu. What I want id for the menu to be hidden without being refreshed with the filter first.

It should be noted that this only occurs when using CSS transitions which I am using to fade the menu out.

Here is a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/V3P8wMuPMT2ROwcCIKdJ?p=preview) to illustrate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/qm7vLZkgco3PBXBSLlKF?p=preview). I basically gave your menu time to finish its animation before setting the value. Relevant code is as follows:

```
$scope.selectItem = function(id){
    $scope.isActive = false;
    $timeout(function(){
        $scope.query.id = id;
    }, 250);
}
```

...and the HTML using the newly created selectItem method:

```
<div class="xtab-typeahead" ng-controller="xTabTypeAheadCtrl">

  <input type="text" class="xtab-typeahead-search" placeholder="{{type}}" ng-model="query.id" ng-focus="showMenu()" ng-init="query.id = undefined" />
  <button ng-click="toggleMenu()">Show/Hide</button>

  <ul class="xtab-typeahead-menu" ng-class="{true:'active',false:''}[isActive]">
    <li ng-repeat="item in menuItems | filter:query" 
        ng-click="selectItem(item.id)">
      {{item.id}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. This works, but I can't help but feel that it is working against Angular in some way. Is the general approach I've adopted perhaps not best practice which is thus requiring this remedial technique?

Comment: I believe your hunch is correct. Typically this sort of behavior is encapsulated within a directive. Since you've broken its component pieces out into the view, this is what it takes to get it working. Had your question had to do with getting the directive working, the answer would have been different. Glad this works for you though.